# Search and get a list of matching LDAP users in Django

Tags: python, django, search, active-directory, ldap

I am using `django-auth-ldap` as my backend to authenticate to my LDAP directory. All my configurations are in `settings.py` and I am able to authenticate myself without problems.

However, I have no clue how to search the LDAP directory and get a list of users that match the first few characters entered in an input field.

I do not want to repeat myself in the view. I want to basically do something like `user_list = LDAPBackend().search(term)`, where term is a string entered in an input field on the page. I then return a JSON dump of `user_list` back to the page to populate the dropdown list on the page.

Here are code snippets of what I already have:

*Sending characters entered to the Django view via Ajax:*

JS loaded on `$(document).ready()`:

```
$("input#people").autocomplete({
                source: "{% url 'people_search' %}",
                minLength: 3,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    //process selected user
                }
            });
```

*Receive entered text in a Django view:*

```
def people_search(request):
    term = request.GET.get('term') # term => text sent from the page
    user_list = []
    user_list = LDAPBackend().search(term) # search does not exist. I need to populate this array with all users that match the captured term.
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(user_list))
```

`settings.py`:

```
# LDAP Authentication
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, NestedGroupOfNamesType

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://mydomain.com:3268'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = 'my_uname'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = 'my_pass'
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("DC=site,DC=domain,DC=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(&(objectClass=*)(sAMAccountName=%(user)s))")
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("DC=site,DC=domain,DC=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=group)")
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = NestedGroupOfNamesType()

AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {
    ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL: 0,
    ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: 0,
}

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail",
}

AUTH_LDAP_PROFILE_ATTR_MAP = {
    "employee_id": "employeeID",
}


AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
```

**Note:** The view `people_search` is decorated by `@login_required`. If I am not authenticated, I am redirected to the login page where I am able to successfully do `user = LDAPBackend().authenticate(username=username, password=password)`

I see `AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH` in settings.py, but I am not sure how to use it. The documentation did not really help me.

Also, ideally, I would like to make the search as fast as possible. In Microsoft Outlook, I am able to quickly search the LDAP directory. I believe all the users are [cached](http://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/performance.html) on my computer. I am okay to have all users cached on my Django server.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @shailenTH Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @Prats Unfortunately, I can't answer that anymore. I am not doing Django anymore now. I am hoping you find a solution, post it here, and I can mark it as an accepted answer :)

Answer (score -3):

To search for objects in the case where the object name is not known but some characters from the object name are known, use the lowest possible search scope and use a substring filter. The filter below is a substring filter:

```
(cn=shail*)
```

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Comment: The links are all dead (as of 2015/05/17) and the answer does not even address the problem of the user.